# Does SCM_RIGHTS have any portable meaning?

Tags: posix, unix-socket

I understand how ancillary data with type SCM_RIGHTS can be used to send file descriptors between processes on Linux. But all IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 has to [say](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) about it is:

> SCM_RIGHTS
>
> ```
> Indicates that the data array contains the access rights to be sent or received.
> ```

What does that mean? Is there any portable meaning to ancillary data of type SCM_RIGHTS?

Comment: I have no idea, but I don't imagine there are any implementations where it means something other than an array of file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

This is because,
UNIX file descriptors can be considered as a token of authority. It refers to a value that references an object along with an associated set of access rights.

> Please read about [Capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security)

Comment: Is this specified in the standard? I understand the history of SCM_RIGHTS and how it's used on actual implementations, but my question was about the formal POSIX standard.